# Joining two data frames by multiple similar columns while maintaining non-overlapping data in R

Tags: r, for-loop, merge, left-join

I've been working on a for-loop that will automatically pull data from excel sheets (each excel file is one observation) and summarize it into a larger data frame. Eventually I would like to create a data frame where each row contains the summary data of each log. I have written the code to accurately summarize the excel files but hit a problem when joining the rows because the summary data frames don't contain all the same columns so I can't use rbind. Below is an example of the format that I have ended up with for my summarized excel sheets:

```
final <- data.frame("BCE_2_Dur" = c(92013), "BCE_2_Freq" = c(1), "BCD_1_Dur" = c(228804), "BCD_1_Freq"= c(7), "BSL_3_Dur" = c(100191), "BSL_3_Freq" = c(3))
```

Where each excel summary may have different codes (behaviors we saw in animals) at the top that match an existing full ethogram but will not necessarily include behaviors from the whole ethogram (if they're not seen).

Since this is in a for-loop I've been trying to solve the problem by just creating an empty data frame that looks like this:

```
empty <- data.frame("BCE_1_Dur" = c(0), "BCE_1_Freq" = c(0), "BCE_2_Dur" = c(0), "BCE_2_Freq" = c(0), "BCE_3_Dur" = c(0), "BCE_3_Freq" = c(0), "BCD_1_Dur" = c(0), "BCD_1_Freq"= c(0),"BCD_2_Dur" = c(0), "BCD_2_Freq"= c(0),"BCD_3_Dur" = c(0), "BCD_3_Freq"= c(0),"BSL_1_Dur" = c(0), "BSL_1_Freq" = c(0),"BSL_2_Dur" = c(0), "BSL_2_Freq" = c(0),"BSL_3_Dur" = c(0), "BSL_3_Freq" = c(0))
```

And then trying to bind them together using left_join since I want to keep all the columns in empty but fill in with columns that match in final. To provide values for the "by" argument in left_join I create a list (again this has to function within the for-loop so the list would change for every loop passed) by the column names of final:

```
namesfinal<-names(final)
namesfinal<-paste("'",as.character(namesfinal),"'",collapse=", ",sep="")
namesfinal<-paste("c","(",namesfinal,")",sep="")
```

Then I run the list into the left_join code:

```
Sum_Final <- left_join(x = empty, y = final, by = namesfinal)
```

This throws an error:
Error: `by` can't contain join column `c('BCE_2_Dur', 'BCE_2_Freq', 'BCD_1_Dur', 'BCD_1_Freq', 'BSL_3_Dur', 'BSL_3_Freq')` which is missing from LHS

My intention was to then rbind() Sum_Final to itself at the end of the loop. however, I can't get past the error. I've tried looking it up and running different versions of namesfinal through the code (e.g. 'BCE_2_Dur'='BCE_2_Dur') but get the same errors. Does anyone have a fix and/or another solution that may work within a for-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a for loop or a join. You can do this using `lapply` and `plyr::rbind.fill()` -

```
filenames <- list.files("path to folder with all files", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
ldf <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)
final_df <- plyr::rbind.fill(ldf)
```

`rbind.fill` will bind all the dataframes and fill non-matching columns with `NA`